# Can you specify preferred default media type for a single path in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey, content-negotiation

I have a Jersey application which has been converted to Spring MVC.  One piece of functionality that I don't see a way to port directly over is the ability, per path, to specify the preferred media type if none is specified.  In Jersey, I could specify the "qs" property on the media type, and it would use that to determine which response type to send if none were specified (or if multiple options were specified in the Accept header, I believe this value was multiplied by the quality scores specified).

```java
@Produces("application/json")
@GET
@Path("/some/path")
public Response preferredResponseType() {
  //Implementation goes here
}

@Produces({"application/schema+json;qs=0.9"})
@GET
@Path("/some/path")
public Response otherResponseType() {
  //Implementation goes here
}
```

In this example, if I do a `GET` request against `/some/path` with no Accept header, it will return the `application/json` response.

I don't see any easy way to do this in Spring MVC, particularly not if I want to restrict the default to applying to just that one endpoint (there are other endpoints in the app that should have a different preferred default).  I do see that there is a way to globally set a default content type (per the "defaultContentType" and "defaultContentTypeStrategy" methods in `ContentNegotiationConfigurer`), but that does not easily address the per-path use case.

Is there an easy way to achieve per-path media type defaults different from the application global default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring issue [19050](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19050) requests this functionality.  Per the conversation there, it looks like there is no simple way to declaratively specify the default content type to use.  Furthermore, the Spring team has closed the issue with a decision not to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The "defaultContentTypeStrategy" allows to provide your own ContentNegotiationStrategy to use. It has access to the full request so you can make path based decisions possibly with the an AntPathMatcher to support patterns easily.

Comment: It looks like while this strategy makes it *possible*, it certainly doesn't make it easy.  It would be difficult to communicate that I want a particular controller/controller method to have a certain default.  I'd either have to hardcode the relevant paths, or write a bunch of code to support this usage.  Either way, the default behavior for the controller (or method) would be well-removed from the actual controller/method.  Plus AntPathMatcher won't necessarily work if a particular path matches multiple controller methods.

Comment: Continuing the previous comment, there also doesn't appear to be a way to get from the provided NativeWebRequest to the actual controller/controller method that would be called.